# What are these things that look like vaporators?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

At the very start of Rogue One, we see several objects that look like this:

[image]

This looks very similar to a moisture vaporator from A New Hope:

[image]

Moreover, we learn that these objects are used for farming. However, it seems unlikely that the ones in Rogue One are used for moisture farming, since: (the following spoiler is extremely minor)

> it rains a short time after we first see them - and the presence of mosses and very green grassland suggest that this is not a rare event in this climate. It's also worth noting that we don't see any evidence of crops or livestock, just green ungrazed grassland and bare rock.

Given this, my question is, what are these objects and what are they used for on this world? What does this farm produce?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Rogue One: Ultimate Visual Guide](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Star-Wars-Rogue-Ultimate-Visual-x/dp/146545263X) identifies them as [Moisture Vaporators](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Moisture_vaporator), with the taller ones very much the same as the ones on the Lars homestead. They're needed because the atmosphere, while breathable and moist, tends to be a bit rich in metals for comfort when it comes to irrigating plants and drinking water.

[image: Vaporators]

[image: Vaporators]

> In worlds with minimal water, vaporators work to condense and filter
>   moisture from the air. **The Lah'mu hydrosphere is abundant, but the
>   zinc, chlorine, iron, cobalt, nitrogen and boron content of the soil
>   makes the groundwater unpleasant to drink.** The Ersos use hardy
>   Pretormin Environmental GX-8 condenser units to distill water vapor
>   from the air. The chemical content is condensed into a storage hopper,
>   where Galen and his droids collect and reconstitute it to fill other
>   needs.

As to *what* he's farming on his farm, the Visual Guide and the official novelisation are both in agreement that it's

> "Crops".

Comment: This appears to be the official answer, so +1, accepted and happy Christmas! If the problem is just with the groundwater I'm not sure why they don't just collect the runoff from the farmhouse roof, but I'm sure they must have their reasons.

Comment: @Nathaniel - I'd assume the same issues about heavy metal poisoning would apply.

Comment: Well usually when water evaporates it loses the impurities it's mixed with, which is why you can purify water by distilling it. If the rainwater has a lot of impurities it must be getting them from the atmosphere as it condenses again - but if the atmosphere is full of that stuff it's pretty weird that it's breathable. (To be clear, I think what you said probably is what the writers intended, it's just that I know more about the science than they do.)

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple and quick way to get up to speed in an isolated area with purified and drinkable water. They can be [bought for up to 500 credits](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Moisture_vaporator) and once in place allow "for up to 1.5 litres of harvest."

Another option, the placement of those vaporators was on the fields themselves, they could have been providing fresh water to the farmlands.