# Why is Ersos' house on Lah'mu so similar to Lars' homestead?

Tags: star-wars, rogue-one

When I watched *Rogue One*, of the millions of questions I asked myself (most of which were admittedly a variation of "why?"), there was one that stuck with me from beginning to end.  What is up with Galen's house on Lah'mu?  It was identical to Uncle Owen's house on Tatooine, right down to the blue milk.

This bugged me because it seems weird that two completely different planets with completely different resources would favour identical architectural styles.  Star Wars usually does a great job of depicting very different cultures through set design alone, but here they essentially copy-pasted Uncle Owen's moisture farm house.

My question is this:  Is there an in-universe justification for why Galen's house on Lah'mu would look so similar to the buildings you'd expect to see on Tatooine?

Comment: Because form follows function. It's a moisture farm. You need moisture vaporators, somewhere to live and crops to farm.

Comment: But Lah'mu was a lush and green planet.  Moisture farming makes sense on a dust ball like Tatooine, but why would you need a moisture farm on a planet that clearly has abundant sources of water?

Comment: Asked and answered here; [What are these things that look like vaporators?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/148330/what-are-these-things-that-look-like-vaporators)

Comment: Nicely spotted Valorum.  That does answer my question quite nicely.  Should I mark my question as a duplicate or is it different enough to stand on it's own?

Comment: If you think it works as a dupe, then you can mark it as such.